# Measure examples, abs continuous and mutualy singular

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I have trouble findind an **example** of a complex measure ($\lambda$) and a positive measure ($\mu$) which $\lambda$ is absolute continuous with respect $\mu$, i.e, $\lambda<<\mu$.

Also an **example** of two measures that are mutually singular.

Comment: For the first, let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ a $\mu$-integrable function, then $\lambda(\cdot)=\int_{(\cdot)} f\mathrm d\mu$ is a.c. w.r.t. $\mu$.

Comment: For the second, take two distinct Dirac measures

Comment: of course $\lambda =0$ will work on the first question